# Hiding unused tab in Acumatica

Tags: cloud, erp, acumatica

In the ERP Acumatica, I am binding a tab to a view that is not my main view. How can I hide this tab when the current element of my view is null?

Comment: A very detailed answer to this question is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030174/hiding-a-tab-from-the-user-interface-dynamically

Answer (score 4):

In Acumatica a tab is automatically hidden when it contains no visible content. You should either use `PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<*Field*>(*YourDataView*.Cache, object, **false**)` for input controls or `*YourDataView*.AllowSelect = **false**` for a grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can invisible it in the customization design mode. In the design mode, choose Control Tree and navigate to the Tab Item. Select tab item that you want to invisible and in it Attributes, set the value of Visible to False (in the attribute collection Ext Props)