# Make a tab invisible

Tags: acumatica

I would like to make the activities tab not visible in the screen CR306000.

[image]

I used the following code, but the result is KO, while it works on other tabs

```
    Base.Activities.AllowInsert = false;
    Base.Activities.AllowUpdate = false;
    Base.Activities.AllowDelete = false;
    Base.Activities.AllowSelect = false;


<px:PXTabItem RepaintOnDemand="False" Text="Activities" LoadOnDemand="False">
```

Comment: Do you want to hide it in a specific case or always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the AllowSelect = false on the DataView itself set it on the [DataView's Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030174/hiding-a-tab-from-the-user-interface-dynamically). That should do the trick

`Base.Activities.**Cache**.AllowSelect = false;`

Alternatively, you can either configure the Visibility Expression or just set the Visible to false from the aspx.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly, but why this tab does not work like the others?